# WPF - How do i insert my proxy credentials in WebBrowser Control

Tags: wpf, proxy, networking, browser, credentials

I'm using a `webbrowser` `control` in WPF to show a virtual earth map, but because  I'm developing behind a `proxy` of my company, every time I try to see the map, I have to insert my credentials.

I would like to insert them automatically in the c# code, how can I achieve that?

I already try in the navigating event of the web browser using:

```
void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("u007239", "****", "****");
    //e.WebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = credential;

}
```

But this doesn't work because I'm getting that `e.webrequest` is a `null object`.

all the help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just put the following in your app.config?

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true"></defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```